# Single '}' possible encountered in format string

Tags: python, printing

is it possible to concat string when using `.format()`?

```
_NACHKOMMASTELLEN = 3

print("  {0:." + str(_NACHKOMMASTELLEN) + "f}".format(round(V_values[0], _NACHKOMMASTELLEN)), end='')
```

I get the error:

> Single '}' encountered in format string

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your string in parenthesis:

```
print(("  {0:." + str(_NACHKOMMASTELLEN) + "f}").format(round(V_values[0], _NACHKOMMASTELLEN)), end='')
      ^                                        ^
```

So that `"  {0:." + str(_NACHKOMMASTELLEN) + "f}"` will be formated instead of `"f}"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are below 3.6 you can double-format:

```
_NKS = 3   # shortened for 79 line char limit
V_values = [3.123456789]
print("  {{:.{}f}}".format(_NKS ).format(round(V_values[0], _NKS )))
```

The first `format` puts the `3` inplace of `{}` and converts the double `{{` and`}}` to single `{` and `}` - the resulting string `{:.3f}` is then used for the second `format` .

As pointed out by @user2357112 in the comment, format is better then I though. This just works as well:

```
print("  {:.{}f}".format(round(V_values[0], _NKS ),_NKS ))
```

Output:

```
  3.123
```

---

You do not need to if you already use 3.6 - f-strings deal better with it:

```
_NACHKOMMASTELLEN = 3
V_values = [3.123456789]
print(f"  {round(V_values[0], _NACHKOMMASTELLEN):.{_NACHKOMMASTELLEN}f}")
V_values = [3.1]
print(f"  {round(V_values[0], _NACHKOMMASTELLEN):.{_NACHKOMMASTELLEN}f}")
```

Output:

```
  3.123
  3.100
```

Comment: You don't need to double-format. `str.format` [already supports nested replacement fields](https://ideone.com/WC4H3R).